# Installing gender php extension

Tags: php, pecl

I'm trying to use the gender extension for php on a new install of Linux Mint 19.

I installed php 5.6 and 7 by adding Ondřej Surý PPA to install different versions of PHP – PHP 5.6, PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1 on Ubuntu system. I'm using the 5.6 version of php for my project.

And now I'm trying to install the php gender extension by following the example at https://gist.github.com/wowo/6154154 which instructs me to:

```
# install gender http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gender.php
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
sudo pecl install gender

# generate data
mkdir ~/gender
sudo pear run-scripts pecl/gender

# enable module
echo 'extension=gender.so' >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

So all that seems to work ok, it asks me "Where the names dictionary file must be saved? The saved dictionary can be modified and read in at the run time. Otherwise the compiled in dictionary will be used." And I put in /home/mycomp/gender because that's where the mkdir made the folder 'gender'

Then in a test script I have:

```
<?php

use Gender\Gender;
$gender = new Gender();

printf("Wojciech is %s\n",
    $gender->get('Wojciech', Gender::POLAND) == Gender::IS_MALE
    ? 'Male'
    : 'Not male');
// prints Wojciech is Male

printf("Anna is %s\n", 
    $gender->get('Anna', Gender::POLAND) == Gender::IS_FEMALE
    ? 'Female'
    : 'Not female');
// prints Anna is Female
```

But I'm getting the error:

Fatal error: Class 'Gender\Gender' not found in /var/www/html/test/index.php on line 4

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Have you checked whether this extension was properly enabled? You should find it in the output of `phpinfo()`

Comment: I checked phpinfo but theres no mention of gender. What do you reckon I've done wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted your webserver after activating the extension? Have you thought about adding the extension not only to the CLI configuration, but also to the webserver configuration if you call the script using a browser?

Comment: Yeah, i restarted apache. How do i add the extension to the webserver? The only instructions I've found online describe what I've done already. Thanks for helping btw

Comment: There should be another `php.ini` - and `phpinfo()` will help you to find it. There you have to add the same line you've added to the other ini

Comment: I've added extension=gender.so in all the php.ini files i can find. In particular, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini and restarted apache. Doesn't seem to help :-(

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` tell you about that - does it list these two files? Is there anything logged to the Apache log on startup?